# Is graduate certificate the right thing to do in Australia for an expat who has a Masters degree in same stream from a foreign college

Tags: human-resources, australia, certification

I have a Masters degree in Human resource from a foreign Uni. I recently migrated to Australia and want to continue in the Human resource domain. In order to get some exposure to the local laws and work ethics I wanted to enroll myself for a course at one of the local Universities. Is a graduate diploma or graduate certificate the correct level as per Australian Qualification framework (AQF) for me ?

I am more inclined to a shorter duration course and as such inclined towards Graduate certificate in Human resource.

Please suggest

Comment: Which country is your original degree from? That's the deciding factor I'd say.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the "standard" timings here in Australia, you have:

- Grad Cert is 6 months full time (1 year part time) = 1/3 of a Masters
- Grad Dip is 12 months full time (2 years part time) =  2/3 of a Masters, and
- Masters is 18 months full time (3 years part time).

If you already a Masters in HR from a recognised foreign university, then a Grad Cert or Grad Dip in HR wouldn't be of much value.  If, however, your degree is not recognised, then your best bet is to talk to the institution you are considering enrolling in to see what advice they can give you for gaining appropriate qualifications for Australia.

We can't give you advice on what you should do, it's far best to talk to the institutions themselves and they can advise you of what you would require and if your degree is already appropriate for working in this country.

Comment: Is there a standard framework to know if my university is a recognized university or is it something that will differ from college to college (which I hope is not) ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.  It really is best to talk to someone who is versed in your specific field.  I suggest academic institutions as they would be well placed to understand what level of Australian-recognised qualification your Masters is equivalent to.